# Can we use google play game services - leaderboards, achievements and turn based multiplayer without a google ID

Tags: google-play-games

Because I was my game to be easy to pick up and play, can I somehow use Google Play Game Services - Leaderboards, Achievements and Turn-based Multiplayer without asking the player to sign-in with his google ID?

Can I generate some other form of authentication? Perhaps generating a temporary ID on the device or by using a custom server side code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure to use those features of Google Play Games Services, it requires users to auth with their Google account. Even just to make calls to the APIs, it requires auth with a Google account. Maybe you can do something weird like, authenticating on behalf of all your users and storing all the information on your server with some sort of user identification, but that completely defeats the purposes of even using Play Games Services.